# VIM search and replace regex - how to keep the search string intact and adding to it?

Tags: regular-expression, search, replace, search-replace

I'd like to learn how to search and replace in VIM - keeping the search string intact and adding to it.

Take this as a simple example. See image below. I copied a simple python script written for python2 and the goal is to make it compatible for python3. The print lines needs to be encapsulated with `()`.

I've entered `:%s/".*"` to regex all lines within two `"`. Now I'd like to add `()` on top of that `string -> (STRING)`. So I have to somehow reference that search string and add to it.

Something like this

```
:%s/".*"/(SEARCHSTRING)
```

[image]

Comment: To convert script from Python 2 to Python I strongly recommend 2to3.py: ``C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py -f print -f has_key -f tuple_params -f ne -f dict -f map -f filter -f except -f raise -f numliterals -w "myscript.py"``

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. But I just used this script as a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&` or `\0`:

`:%s/".*"/(&)/`

Comment: Teach a man how to fish: [`:h sub-replace-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-special)

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was an answer. Didn't find it when searching online. Much appreciated.